# LDAP authentication Support in Node js

Tags: node.js, ldapconnection

I have installed ldapauth using `npm install ldapauth` and I installed ldapjs.
I tried with the following code:

```
var sys   = require('sys'),
ldapauth  = require('./ldapauth');

var scheme    = 'ldap',
    ldap_host = 'abc.com',
    ldap_port = 369,
    username  = 'xxx',
    password  = 'xxx'
    base      = "DC=abc,DC=xyz,DC=com";
    filter    = "(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName= 3025141))";

console.log("Authentication Check");

ldapauth.authenticate(scheme, ldap_host, ldap_port, username, password,
  function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {  
          console.log('Authenticated ! ! ! ! ! : ' + result);
      }
  });

//ldap authentication Search
ldapauth.search(ldap_host, ldap_port, username, password, base, filter,
  function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        sys.puts(err);
      } else {
        sys.puts('Search: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
      }
  });
```

I tried in mac but I am getting `Segmentation fault: 11` error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:1389'
});

client.bind('cn=root', 'secret', function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('authenticated');
  }
});

client.unbind(function(err) {
});
```

I used ldapjs client to authenticate. It should'nt be a problem.
[here is the link to ldapjs client doc](http://ldapjs.org/client.html)

Comment: This is only Bind, after login you still don't know the user information except the username